# Preventing other GUI applications from stealing focus?

Tags: gui, mate-desktop, productivity, focus, metacity

How can I prevent other applications from stealing focus from the active window?  I have found solutions for other window managers, but nothing for "Metacity (Marco)" (the window manager of the MATE desktop manager).

I don't want to have to specify every time which window must be "always on top", unless it can be done automatically every time I switch to a new window.

I have determined the window manager by running `wmctrl -m`.

EDIT:

I have tried switching the `focus-new-windows` flag from `smart` to `strict` for both Gnome and Mate(Marco):

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-new-windows strict
$ gsettings set org.mate.Marco.general focus-new-windows strict
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: AFAIK, MATE is a desktop environment. It isn't a window manager. Depending on which version of MATE you're using, you may have a choice of window managers to choose from.

Comment: @DKBose: Thanks for the observation.  The window manager is Metacity.  I have updated my question.

Comment: Please see if this (old) blog post is of help: http://bertrandbenoit.blogspot.in/2011/09/change-window-behavior-to-prevent-focus.html

Comment: Thanks, but `gconftool-2 ` says that the value `/apps/metacity/general/no_focus_windows` does not exists (and indeed the whole `/apps/metacity` tree is missing.

Comment: well... `focus-new-window` wont work since the description says: *This option provides additional control over how newly created windows get focus. It has two possible values; "smart" applies the user's normal focus mode, and "strict" results in windows **started from a terminal** not being given focus.*

Comment: if you found solutions for other window manager, with the adapted command `gsettings set com.linuxmint.desktop mate-window-manager marco` you can maybe use one of them! **...and post your solution if you succeed! ;-)**

Comment: interesting... after playing around a little bit, i noticed it also depends on the **application and launcher** (?) which you are using: firefox for example is not stealing focus if you start it via shortcut from the panel or desktop, but it does if you start it via the normal mint menu. and on the other side libreoffice is stealing focus whatever starter you use!

Comment: In the end, I switched to Xfce, so I am not using Metacity anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to install an extension to eliminate the behavior in gnome-shell, where gnome displays a "Window is ready" notification rather than giving the new window focus. The extension "Noannoyance" appears to be the best maintained, but alternatively "Steal My Focus" or "Focus my window" probably still work fine.

link: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2182/noannoyance/